# Visual Studio Code не видит закрытие скриты JS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, скрипт

#### Описание

Когда работаешь с обычным JavaScript (баз TypeScript, серверов и.т.п.) есть один неудобный момент: Visual Studio Code не видит скрипты которые не открыты в данный момент:

[image]

Даже если они в той же папке. Ошибка пропадает если открыть нужный скрипт.

[image]

Держать все скрипты постоянно открытым очень неудобно, особенно когда у тебя их куча:

[image]

#### Вопрос

Есть ли какие-нибудь настройки, плагины, конфигурации, или что-то еще, что поможет увидеть скрипты даже когда они закрыты?

Comment: Если такое только с расширением `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly`, значит в нем какой-то баг, который в скором исправят. В целом не вижу смысла использовать данное расширение.

Comment: @OliverPatterson баг, не баг уже 2 года так. Не думаю, что исправят. Оно добавляет типизацию в JS, что удобно. Видимо придется искать замену.

Comment: @OliverPatterson ошибочка вышла. Расширение тут не при чем. Я отключил его и ничего не изменилось. Так встроенный в Visual Studio Code JS реагирует.

Comment: Кхм.. Не понимаю почему оно должно вообще подсвечивать, если нету импортов.

Comment: И вам не нужен `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly`, оно лишь включает все саааамые новые фишки тайп скрипта.

Comment: @OliverPatterson две разные скрипты которые находятся в одном папке и подключены через HTML не подсвечиваются когда один из них закрыт. Не использовал импорты.

Comment: НУ вообще я все же не понимаю, почему редактор должен вообще связывать в вашем случае..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144734/discussion-between-eccs0103-and-oliver-patterson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Ответ

Нашел необычный подход. Из себя представляет группа трюков, результат которого решает проблему.

Нам надо "импортировать" другой скрипт в текущий, при этом не трогая сам Java Script. Для этого мы используем команду из JSDoc - [`@typedef`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) вместе с командой `import("")`. Получаем вот такую строку:

```js
/** @typedef {import("./modules/color.js")} */
```

После чего мы получим ошибку, что

> Файл '...' не является модулем

Нам надо игнорировать эту ошибку, поэтому добавляем `// @ts-ignore` в предыдущую строку. Получаем такую конструкцию

```js
// @ts-ignore
/** @typedef {import("./modules/color.js")} */
```

После чего все данные из другого скрипта будут "импортированы" в текущий скрипт.

---

#### Дополнение

При чем, если мы "импортируем" скрипт в котором уже "импортированы" другие скрипты, то данные из них так же будут добавлены текущий скрипт.